# Функция fprintf

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как будет выглядеть функция `fprintf`

```
int fprintf( FILE *stream, const char *format, ... );
```

в случае, если я пользуюсь `ofstream &fp` вместо `FILE*fp`?

```
ofstream fp("oops.txt");
```

Здесь `fp` не является указателем, как обычно бывает. Как тогда сделать?

п.с. или какую функцию лучше использовать, чтобы занети в файл данные, если используется `ofstream`?

Comment: Лучше не мешать все в кучу. Используйте C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция fprintf не нужна. В C++ для записи в потоки (не только ofstream, а всех унаследованных от ostream классов) используется оператор <<

```
fp << "Hello, world!" << endl;
fp << "2 + 2 = " << (2 + 2) << endl;
```

Подробно про ввод-вывод в файлы можно почитать например по [ссылке](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: аа,ок.
спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы пользуетесь ofstream, то fprintf не будет выглядеть никак. Они из разных библиотек.